# How to Fix Kyocera M6230cidn printer

Tags: printers, network-printers

I need some help with this one.

I have a Kyocera M6230cidn printer that always randomly  jams just before exiting, paper jammed in rear cover.

I am no expert by any means and my knowledge is very limited with this model. Hopefully you guys can help

Please feel free to request any more info.

Thanks

I checked that the cassette is set correctly with paper set on A4. The rollers are all in good condition as well. We have many machines like this but this is a first that I am experiencing this issue.